# Java 8: passing paramenter to anonymous function during call

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm not able to implement this in Java 8, it is a simple anonymous function

```
// definde
Runnable callback = (param) -> {
    for(int i = 0; i < param; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
};

// call consume it
callback.run(10);
```

Comment: That `for` loop can also be written as `IntStream.range(0, param).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: `Runnable` exists since Java 1.0. Every Java developer should know that its `run()` method doesn’t accept any argument, that’s not related to Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Runnable` doesn't take a parameter, but [`IntConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntConsumer.html) does:

```
IntConsumer callback = (param) -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < param; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
};

callback.accept(10);
```

You can also browse the [other functional interfaces in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).